# Is 'We are impossible to master English in a short time' unnatural?

Tags: expressions, infinitives, subjects, to-infinitive

I'm Chinese, my teacher told me don't use the means of code-switching to learn foreign languages, she made an instance for this:

Chinese:

> 我们不可能在很短的时间内就掌握英语。

Divided into words by gaps:

> 我们 不可能 在 很短的 时间 内 就 掌握 英语。

Literal meaning by words: *we, impossible, in/on/at, very short, time, in/inside/within, just, master(v.), English.*

She said the correct expression is like:

> It is impossible for us to master English in a short time.

But Chinese perhaps express it as follow due to the code-switching, which is incorrect:

> We are impossible to master English in a short time.

What I want to ask is, does this 'incorrect' sentence sounds really incorrect or unnatural in native speakers' opinion? May you tell me?

Comment: note in your English gloss  "we are impossible..." you have inserted a new verb "are".   This changes the English to something like "我们很不可能". Perhaps that's just as odd in Chinese.

Comment: Short answer: yes, completely incorrect and unnatural.   "We are" and "It is" are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it sounds completely unnatural. I guess a native-speaker's mind would quickly replace "We are" with "It is", and immediately follow it with "for us".

Answer (score 2):

[我们] [不可能] [在 很短的 时间 内] [就 掌握 英语]。

> It is impossible for us to master English in a short time.

is fine.

> We are impossible to master English in a short time.

is ungrammatical.  Having the English terms follow the word sequence of the Chinese sentence would give

> [We] [can't possibly] [in a short time][master English].

which does not sound as good as

> We can't possibly master English in a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at an easier sentence first:

> The book is green.

This sentence describes the book and names an attribute that the book has, namely the book's color.

> We are impossible.

would follow the same principle. But you *do* exist, therefore you can't be impossible ;)

What you want to do is describe an attribute not of yourself, but of learning the English language. So, a simplified version of your sentence could be

> It is impossible to master English.

Then, you expand this sentence with additonal information:

> It is impossible to master English *in a short time*.
> It is impossible *for us* to master English in a short time.

As a side note, it would be a topic of its own where the "it" in "It is impossible" comes from ;) So for this question, you may want to just accept it.